# Getting ECONNREFUSED after certificate prompt when connecting to Pure-FTPd via TLS, plain FTP works

Tags: ftp, ssl, ftps, pure-ftpd

I have setup a new FTP server using Pure-FTPd and Ubuntu 20.04. I can connect to my server without a problem when I'm not activating TLS.

First I created a self-signed certificate with the following command:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/pure-ftpd.pem -out /etc/ssl/private/pure-ftpd.pem -days 3650
```

Then I activated TLS with this command and also restarted the service:

```
echo "2" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/TLS
systemctl restart pure-ftpd
```

In FileZilla, I use the explicit setting to connect. The certificate shows up correctly. It even says that the TLS connection has been established, but then I receive the ECONNREFUSED error message.

The following ports are opened on the firewall: 21, 22, 989, 990

UFW is deactivated on the server itself.

There is nothing in the syslogs or Pure-FTPd logs. I am out of ideas and really hope someone can help me here.

[image: Filezilla]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get certificate prompt, you *can connect*. The *ECONNREFUSED* probably refers to the data connection for directory listing, as you have not opened data ports.

In Pure-FTPd you configure the data ports using `--passiveportrange <minport:maxport>` command-line switch. And you need to open those ports in your firewall.

---

Plain unencrypted FTP likely works because your firewall is able to track the unencrypted FTP control connection and open the data ports as needed (in the built-in Windows firewall the feature is called *"stateful FTP filtering"*). That's not possible when the control connection is encrypted.

---

Btw, 990 is used for implicit TLS connections only, you generally do not need it either. And the 989 does not have to be opened for FTP at all.

Comment: Used this command instead of the switch: echo "40110 40210" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/PassivePortRange